# Keyboard shortcuts for Chrome 37's save-password dialog

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

What keyboard shortcuts exist for Chrome 37's save-password dialog (or similar dialogs, like the one about translating a page)?

So far I've noticed that if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, the button to save the password is highlighted; after if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, the button to not save it is highlighted. I can press <kbd>Space</kbd> on either one to activate it (<kbd>Esc</kbd> additionally dismisses the dialog without saving the password). But I can't find any way to drop down the "**Nope**" button to get at "never save for this site"; <kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> don't do anything (on Windows, at least).

Secondarily, what elements are focused before I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice? I can't see anything visually selected; and when the dialog's open, Chrome won't allow me to navigate around the page with the keyboard, like older versions with the password bar/shelf/strip allowed.